# Nextjs: TypeError: unsupported file type: undefined after update to v.11

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js

After update Next to 11 when I'm trying to load an image with:

```
import segmentLogoWhitePng from 'assets/images/my-image.png'
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported file type: undefined (file: undefined)
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

## Latest Update

It works now as of `next@v11.0.1`. No need to follow the steps below.

---

Disable the static images feature for now as a workaround:

```
// next.config.js

module.exports = {
  images: {
    disableStaticImages: true
  }
}
```

---

**Update:** This has been fixed in [next@11.0.1-canary.4](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/releases/tag/v11.0.1-canary.4). Install it:

```sh
$ npm install next@canary
```

See the [related issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/26130) & [the PR](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/26281).

Comment: This works, you know if this will be fixed in future?

Comment: Thanks for this. I was hoping it could be solved in a different way, but I can see that this is the only solution.

Comment: Still getting this error with `^11.1.2`

Comment: Still (or again?) happening in `^12+`. `disableStaticImages` did not help either. Had to move it to the `public` folder and use a relative url instead of `import`.

Comment: Was getting it in `^12.1.6`, until implemented the workaround.

Comment: I'm still getting this in 13.0.6 when using npm next-images

Answer (score 9):

**Disable Static Imports**

-Since version 10.0.0, Next.js has a built-in Image Component and Automatic Image Optimization

The default behavior allows you to import static files such as import icon from './icon.png and then pass that to the src property.
In some cases, you may wish to disable this feature if it conflicts with other plugins that expect the import to behave differently.
You can disable static image imports with the following configuration below.

```
  // next.config.js
  
  images: {
        disableStaticImages: true
    }
```

Comment: this fixed my issue for me - must be an old instance of next and then spinning it up again has this bug - thankyou!

Answer (score 4):

I just removed my image/css loader config from webpack (next.config.js) and it started working.

Comment: Same here, maybe the latest version is overrideen by these old methods

Answer (score 2):

look to the issue in the GitHub repo Fix types for the static image it will be work right now

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/25808

```
  module.exports = {
  images: {
    disableStaticImages: true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `next.config.js` you can add file type checks and handlers. I know that svg can be handled by putting the following code and downloading the npm package @svgr/webpack so there could possibly be a .png equivalent

```
module.exports = {
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: ["@svgr/webpack"],
    });

    return config;
  },
};
```

One example that could work is this code from [this stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67153903/png-images-cannot-be-loaded-nextjs)

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'file-loader',
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    }
};
```

I know this answer wasn't 100%, but hopefully it helps out a little bit