# Image in next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, png

I am trying to simply just render a PNG image that I have placed in the `./public/assets/images` directory in my Next JS project.
I have used the `next-images` package for the same. However, I still keep getting an error saying

> ./public/assets/images/delivery-boy.png
> TypeError: unsupported file type: undefined (file: undefined)

Here's my code for that component

```js
import React from 'react'
import deliveryBoy from '../../../public/assets/images/delivery-boy.png'
import Image from 'next/image'

const MedicalStoreScreen = () => {
    return (
        <div className="med-store-screen" >
            <div className="section-title-container">
                <div className="heading">Medical Store</div>
                <div className="sub-heading">medicine home delivery</div>
            </div>
            <div className="med-store-info-container">
                <div className="img-container">
                    <img src={deliveryBoy} />
                </div>
                <div className="content-container">
                    <div className="content">24/7 Delivery in 30 minutes</div>
                    <div className="content">Upto 30% discount</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default MedicalStoreScreen
```

Here's the code for my `next.config.js` file

```js
const withImages = require('next-images')
module.exports = withImages()
```

Can someone please suggest what's going wrong in rendering this PNG image in my Next JS app?

Comment: Why you need third party package? I mean, it's better for you if you can use the `<Image />` [provided by default](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image).

Comment: Yeah so the think is `<Image/>` has been failing in the latest next Js build so that is why PNG image is not getting detected. You can find the solution for the same here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68008498/nextjs-typeerror-unsupported-file-type-undefined-after-update-to-v-11

Answer (score 1):

You're not utilising the next image when using "img"

Make sure that the image path is also correct. Looks like the issue could be the path: "../../../public/assets/images/delivery-boy.png".

You should also use Image not img. Like this:

```
<Image
   className=""
   src={deliveryBoy} 
   width={10}
   height={10}
   alt=""
/>
```

You can also call the image from the cloud or internet by adding the URL like this:

```
<Image
       className=""
       src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/170811/pexels-photo-170811.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" 
       width={10}
       height={10}
       alt=""
    />
```

Don't forget to add the width, height and alt. You can leave the "alt" blank.

Answer (score 0):

Next.js doesn't allow us to import any image in `.js` file so the following steps can be used to render the image in Next.js:

1. Save or store your image somewhere under the `public` folder (`logo.png` for example)
2. Use the following syntax to render the image: `<img src="/public/images/logo.png" />`.

   - `/public` indicate that file is located inside the public folder,  no need to have anything before it.
   - `/public/image` describes that in the public folder go to the image folder
   - `/public/image/logo.png` full path of the image.

If you try to store the image in any other folder except public, it won't render.

Answer (score 0):

For a "normal" image, you can use an `img` tag.

But as `NextJS` provides image optimization use an `Image` tag from Next and provide dimensions

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This will work, if your image is inside public folder.

No imports is required for images inside "public" dir because next will serve this as a public URL, and your access that image using below method.

```
<Image
   className=""
   src="/assets/images/delivery-boy.png" 
   width={10}
   height={10}
   alt=""
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Import your image like this:

```
import deliveryBoy from "@/public/assets/images/delivery-boy.png"
```

and use Image tag like this:

```
<Image src={deliveryBoy} alt="" width={100} height={100} />
```

don't customize your next.config.js file, it is not needed when you are importing next/image.