# Images loaded using next.js only showing default image and subtext

Tags: javascript, html, image, webpack, next.js

[Images current show up like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuGPe.png)
Looking at the image source, it shows up as `<img class="blur flex-shrink-0 mb-0 mr-3 rounded-full w-14 h-14 lazyloaded" alt="Profile" src="[object Object]">`
Without using `.default` as shown below, the src would be `[object Module]`

I am using next.js 12 (but the same issues happen on 11).

I am loading the images like this (Both the commented and uncommented result in the same):

```
      <Image
        className="flex-shrink-0 mb-0 mr-3 rounded-full w-14 h-14"
        // src={require("../../../content/assets/profile.png").default}
        // webpSrc={require("../../../content/assets/profile.png?webp").default}
        // previewSrc={require("../../../content/assets/profile.png?lqip").default}
        src={require("public/profile_new.png").default}
        webpSrc={require("/public/profile_new.png?webp").default}
        previewSrc={require("/public/profile_new.png?lqip").default}
        alt="Profile"
      />
```

I've tried suggestions from:
[Webpack file-loader outputs [object Module]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59070216/webpack-file-loader-outputs-object-module)
[IMAGE: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45848055/image-you-may-need-an-appropriate-loader-to-handle-this-file-type)
[I can't reference an image in Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59546370/i-cant-reference-an-image-in-next-js)
[Nextjs: TypeError: unsupported file type: undefined after update to v.11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68008498/nextjs-typeerror-unsupported-file-type-undefined-after-update-to-v-11)

Below is my next.config.js. All the parts that have been commented out have at one point been uncommented but have yielded the same result.

```
const optimizedImages = require("next-optimized-images");
module.exports = optimizedImages({
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
      use: [
        options.defaultLoaders.babel,
        {
          loader: "file-loader",
          options: {
            esModule: false,
          },
        },
      ],
    });

    return config;
  },
});
```

Here are my dependencies from `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "imagemin-mozjpeg": "^9.0.0",
    "imagemin-optipng": "^8.0.0",
    "lazysizes": "^5.3.1",
    "lqip-loader": "^2.2.1",
    "next": "^12.0.4",
    "next-compose-plugins": "^2.2.1",
    "next-optimized-images": "^2.6.2",
    "next-themes": "^0.0.14",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-markdown": "^5.0.3",
    "react-syntax-highlighter": "^15.4.3",
    "react-toggle-dark-mode": "^1.0.3",
    "remark-gfm": "^1.0.0",
    "typeface-merriweather": "^1.1.13",
    "typeface-open-sans": "^1.1.13",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webp-loader": "^0.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.0",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.4.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.5",
    "gray-matter": "^4.0.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "postcss": "^8.2.8",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.0.4"
  },
```

File structure: [file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEIsm.png)

Comment: When using `src` in an image, don't `require` it. Just simply `src="../../../content/assets/profile.png"` is what you want. Anyways, don't require any `src` property.

Comment: @code I tried without the require, still the same issue, though in inspect element I can see how that the path is correct (with the weird .png?lqip extension which I believe is deliberate?)

Comment: [Webpack configuration](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-webpack-config) is set under the `webpack` field in `next.config.js`, not `webpackConfig`. You should also use a single `module.exports` in that file, e.g. `module.exports = optimizedImages({ webpack: (config, options) => {...} })`

Comment: @juliomalves I changed my next.config.js to conform but still the same issue. now I'm using:
`module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
      use: [
        options.defaultLoaders.babel,
        {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            esModule: false,
          }
        },
      ],
    })

    return config
  },
}`

Comment: @juliomalves I have updated the post with the current next.config.js. I believe I have followed your advice. Let me know, thanks