# Next js importing public folder image from nested directory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I Have stored my images in public directory and my all codes are in the src folder.

normally when i try to use importing image from `src/page/page.js`
like: `/image/logo/logo-dark.png`
it works but when I am importing images from `src/component/core/BrandLogo` directory it gives me:

**Module not found: Can't resolve '/image/logo/logo-dark.png'**

my `next.config.js` is :

```
const path = require('path')
const withImages = require('next-images')
module.exports = {
  sassOptions: {
    includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, 'src/assets/scss')],
    eslint: {
      // Warning: Dangerously allow production builds to successfully complete even if
      // your project has ESLint errors.
      ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
    },
  },
  images: {
    loader: "imgix",
    path: "",
  }
}
module.exports = withImages({
  fileExtensions: ["jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif"],
  webpack(config, options) {
    return config
  }
})
```

Component Code:

````
import darklogo from '/public/image/logo/logo-dark.png'
import lightLogo from '/image/logo/logo-white.png'
export default function BrandLogo({logoWhite=false,...rest}){
return(
<>
    <img src={darklogo} alt="brand logo" {...rest}/>
</>
)
}```
````

Comment: Please also add the (component) code where you're importing the image.

Comment: Try with relative paths. Like: `import logo from '../public/image/logo.png'` if you have more nested structure just go up to the root. Or set a root path then it's not conflicting to navigate.

Comment: component code updated

Comment: Does this answer your question: [PNG images cannot be loaded | NextJS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67166178/1870780)? Just reference each image by their path in the `public` folder directly in the `<img>`'s `src` prop - no need to import them.

Comment: not actually i was trying to import images from 3 level nested path.

Answer (score 3):

I have solved my problem by editing my `jsconfig.json` file. it looks like below:

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    // "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "paths": {
        "~components/*": ["src/components/*"],
        "~components": ["src/components"],
        "~fonts/*": ["public/fonts/*"],
        "~fonts": ["public/fonts"],
        "~image/*": ["public/image/*"],
        "~image": ["public/image"],
        "~sections": ["src/sections"],
        "~sections/*": ["src/sections/*"],
        "~styled/*": ["src/styles/*"],
        "~styled": ["src/styles"],
        "~scss/*": ["src/styles/scss/*"],
        "~scss": ["src/styles/scss"],
        "~data/*": ["src/data/*"],
        "~data": ["src/data"],
        "@/*": ["node_modules/*"],
        "@": ["node_modules"],
    }
}
```

and my component now looks like this:

```
import darklogo from '~image/logo/logo-dark.png'
export default function BrandLogo({logoWhite=false,...rest}){
  return(
    <>
      <img src={darklogo} alt="brand logo" {...rest}/>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the absolute path to import an image. Needed to use the relative path when importing an image. like- ../public/folder.
The absolute path is only able to use directly with src. Cause, files inside the public can then be referenced by your code starting from the base URL (/).