# How to properly import images and videos in Next js

Tags: reactjs, image, import, next.js

I just want to ask how to properly import images and videos in nextjs? My images doesn't load on nested route page, like this -> localhost:3000/about/missionVision It works on single path though, like this -> localhost:3000/about

This is the code of the component with image that doesn't load on nested route/page.

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";

const Banner= () => {
    return(
        <Fragment>
            <header className="banner">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="logo">
                        <img src="./images/logo.png" alt="our logo"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
        </Fragment>
    )
}

export default Banner;
```

I used to use this format of importing, but there's always an error when I imported videos/mp4 files, plus image doesn't show. ( I migrated cra to next)

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import logo from "./../../public/images/logo.png";

const Banner= () => {
    return(
        <Fragment>
            <header className="banner">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="logo">
                        <img src={ logo }/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
        </Fragment>
    )
}

export default Banner;
```

This is my file structure

```
root folder
    components
        Banner
            -index.js
    page
    public
        images
        videos
```

Thank you!

Edit: This is the error that shows whenever I try to import a video.

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See 
https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: @IlliaChil ,  I edited the post. Please see it, thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question [PNG images cannot be loaded | NextJS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67166178/1870780)? Make sure to use the correct path from `public` folder, without the dot: `<img src="/images/logo.png" alt="our logo" />`.

Comment: @juliomalves I didn't know that the path without the dot works different, and it actually works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Need for import public path just try to access from the public path.
<img src={"/images/xyz.svg"} />

Comment: I'm currently using that, please see the first sample code. The problem with that is that the image won't load on nested page/route, for example -> localhost:3000/about/mission-vision

Comment: I didn't notice the difference of having a dot on the first / on my path and yours. But this works. Thank you.